# UI-Router With RequireJS Throwing Script Error

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, requirejs

I am starter on these 2 libraries. Previously I used ng-view for switching views, and now I am migrating to ui-view with RequireJS.

Here my codes

> index.html

```
...

<body ng-cloack ui-router-styles>
    <div class="ui-view"></div>
</body>

<script src="components/JS/moment.js"></script>
<script src="components/JS/moment_locale-id.js"></script>
<script src="components/JS/require.js" data-main="main.js"></script>

...
```

> main.js

```
require.config({
    waitSeconds: 0,
    baseUrl: '',
    paths: {
        'angular': 'components/JS/angular.min',
        'angularAMD': 'components/JS/angularAMD.min',
        'angular-ui-router': 'components/JS/angular-ui-router.min',
        'angular-ui-router-styles': 'components/JS/angular-ui-router-styles',
        'angular-messages': 'components/JS/angular-messages.min',
        'angular-aria': 'components/JS/angular-aria.min',
        'angular-animate': 'components/JS/angular-animate.min',
        'angular-material': 'components/JS/angular-material.min',
        'angular-locale_id-id': 'components/JS/angular-locale_id-id',
        'angular-moment': 'components/JS/angular-moment.min',
        'moment': 'components/JS/moment'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularAMD': ['angular'],
        'angular-ui-router': ['angular'],
        'angular-locale_id-id': ['angular'],
        'angular-ui-router-styles': ['angular-ui-router'],
        'angular-aria': ['angular'],
        'angular-messages': ['angular'],
        'angular-animate': ['angular'],
        'angular-material': ['angular', 'angular-animate', 'angular-aria', 'angular-messages'],
        'angular-moment': ['moment']
    },
    deps: ['app']
});
```

> app.js

```
define([
        'angularAMD',
        'angular-ui-router',
        'angular-ui-router-styles',
        'angular-material',
        'angular-messages',
        'angular-animate',
        'angular-aria',
        'angular-locale_id-id',
        'angular-moment'
    ],
    function (angularAMD, amMoment) {
        'use strict';
        var app = angular.module('com.malasbelanja.app', ['angularMoment', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'uiRouterStyles']);

        app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $mdThemingProvider, $mdGestureProvider, $sceDelegateProvider, $compileProvider, $mdDateLocaleProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('login', angularAMD.route({
                    url: '/login',
                    templateUrl: 'state/views/login.php',
                    data: {
                        css: ['state/styles/login.css']
                    },
                    /*resolve: {
                        loadController: ['$q',
                            function ($q) {
                                var deferred = $q.defer();
                                require(['state/controllers/login'], function () {
                                    deferred.resolve();
                                });
                                return deferred.promise;
                            }
                        ]
                    },*/
                    controller: 'loginController'
                }))
                .state('register', angularAMD.route({
                    url: '/register',
                    templateUrl: 'state/views/register.php',
                    data: {
                        css: ['state/styles/register.css']
                    }
                }));
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("login");

            $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                .primaryPalette('green', {
                    'default': '900'
                })
                .accentPalette('blue', {
                    'default': '900'
                });
            $mdThemingProvider.theme('dark')
                .primaryPalette('yellow')
                .dark();
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
                return moment(date).format('LL');
            };
            $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled(true);
            $mdGestureProvider.skipClickHijack();
            $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['**']);
        });

        app.controller('loginController', function($scope){
            $scope.login = function(){
                alert('halo');
            };
        });

        app.run(function (amMoment) {
            amMoment.changeLocale('id');
        });

        angularAMD.bootstrap(app);
        return app;

    });
```

But the page goes blank.
Here is the console message:

```
require.js:5 GET http://bismillah/loginController.js 403 (Forbidden)
require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Script error for "loginController"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:5)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:5)
```

Note: http://bismillah is my own virtual sever build on XAMPP

I plan to use a dynamic controller files later, and have founded how to provide them (on the comment block : `app.js`). Now I just want to implementing `controller` that i have defined in `app.js` but I keep getting error. Can you solve it? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Not sure for now, but things I see are: 1. `angular-moment` not depends on `angular` 2. In `app.js` the injection for ` function (angularAMD, amMoment)` is not in the expected order - `'angularAMD',        'angular-ui-router',`

Comment: In `app.js` I only want to skip the other parameters except `angularAMD` and `amMoment`. Did I make it correctly ?

Comment: No. `angularAMD` will go to `angularAMD` but `angular-ui-router` will go to the variable `amMoment`. If you want `amMoment` you need to change the `define` to have `amMoment` as its second require, after `angularAMD`

Comment: Still got the same error.
I see there RequireJS tried to load `loginController` as an actual file since I've never invoke RequireJS to load in `require` nor `define`. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be more easier if you could provide a simple plunker/jsfiddle that mimic your application structure and loading.

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing, I made two separate views then config their states as they are. It works.